# Accessing the Review queue is slow

Tags: support, review-queues

Starting today opening the [Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) of Stack Overflow takes about 15 seconds.

Is it only me or do other users have the same problem?

[image]

Comment: Intermittently over the past week or so, and especially now.

Comment: @Stijn not a dupe: the one you refer was posted on Apr 17 and [fixed on May 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230925/165773). Fixed bug strikes back

Comment: @gnat Vote retracted.

Comment: @Stijn I review daily for about a month and statement on May 2 fix matches my observations

Comment: @gnat yesterday and the days before was all fine with the review queue, but since today it is getting worse.

Comment: ["There's a bandwagon effect going on: people are agreeing with existing close votes without thoroughly evaluating whether they're accurate."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144557/bandwagon-effect-in-close-votes)

Comment: The problem with the review queue seems to be resolved. So the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved. Since today the Review queue is working normaly again.