# Stack Overflow review page very slow to load?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review-queues

The [root review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) seems to be loading very slowly for me at the moment. About **3 - 6 times slower** than any other page, including the individual Queue pages below and other sites' review pages. My connection is not perfect, but it seems to only be that page.

- Anybody else seeing this?
- Is there any ongoing maintenance causing this?
  (I noticed the site was 'read-only' a few hours back. ~2am UTC 21st Jun)

---

Firefox's Network monitor tool output:

[image]

Note the wait between the first and second responses (~15 seconds).

---

Things look to be running smooth again now. (+48hrs later)  I suppose it being the weekend slowed down the response time.

Any explanation for the degradation from somebody in the know?
I'm just curious and the other similar bug reports I found were never explained.

Comment: It slow for me as well. I guess the cache got cleared and doesn't get loaded again...

Comment: Thanks for the link @rene, as that report was marked resolved I would suggest this is not a dup because the issue has resurfaced (and was never really answered anyway).

Comment: Possibly ironically, the dup target looks to have been originally marked as a dup of a previous similar report and retracted for the same reason I stated above.

Comment: Slow for me too. Loads in about 15 - 17 seconds (enormous by today's standards), about 10 times slower than any other page on the site.

Comment: There's an [identical bug report](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253972/accessing-the-review-queue-is-slow) from back at the start of May that this was previously marked as a duplicate of. It looks like it got resolved within 24hrs but nobody in the know came in to explain why it happened in the first place.

Comment: A [closed post on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229345/stack-overflow-review-button-is-slow-and-test-questions-are-slower) mentions poor caching as a likely culprit but also that things would have improved since the build after that was posted.

Comment: Looks like it's back to normal speed.

Comment: Had been running slow for me too but back to normal now.

Comment: Always slow for me.

Comment: data dump? Was there an ongoing database backup? If that's the case then why would it affect the review 'contents' page only and not anywhere else on the site or even the individual queue stats pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. We had some inefficient review code back in June that (if I remember correctly) was fixed by Jarrod in July via better use of caching. Reviews should now be quick for all users.