# Review page navigation is very slow

Tags: discussion, review-queues

It is almost impossible to review First Posts. Editing takes ages. This week has been particularly bad, but today is awful.

Am I the only one experiencing this? I am aware of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261201/stack-overflow-review-page-very-slow-to-load) but it seems that was a punctual issue. Following that post, here is the network analysis in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: I have no repro on Chrome/Win 10

Comment: No repro here - are other review queues slow for you or only First Posts?

Comment: FWIW, for me the Super User review pages load very slowly (since a couple of days), but other review pages (including SO) load normally.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Well, don't have many to try (not the least because queues are empty), but First Posts stats SE and Triage in SO also run slow.