# Review queues empty?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

I might just be freaking out over nothing, but this is the first time I have ever seen this happen:

[image: EEEMPTYYY]
[image: ALL OF THEEEEM]

Is this a bug, or did a bunch of people actually completely clear the queues? Clicking on them leads to a page saying "This queue has been cleared", so I'm guessing its the latter. However I have never seen this happen before, so I want to be sure.

**EDIT:** Welp, now the rest are empty too.

**EDIT 2:** Logging out reveals this:

[image]

**EDIT 3:** Logging back *in* reveals 6 items in the Documentation queue:

[image]

However, actually clicking on it yields nothing:

[image]

Comment: Rumour has it that this is a result of a cloning experiment on Bhargav Rao gone wrong.

Comment: Lol, nope @Glorfindel. I think it's because they're moving back to the normal data center from the DR. (waiting for Nick's tweet on it, though).

Comment: Can't reproduce, they display the numbers correctly for me.

Comment: @Rizier123 Just refreshed, still showing all 0s for me.

Comment: Are you suspended from review?

Comment: @BhargavRao that move is already complete

Comment: @rene Not that I know of. Also check the edit. Logging out gives the same result.

Comment: My incognito result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IkVj.png no repro of what you see.

Comment: Where are you located in the world? maybe you hit a specific server that is out of sync?

Comment: @rene Odd, in yours the bottom few queues are also at 0, but Help and Improvement, Low Quality, and Documentation aren't. Also I'm in East Europe.

Comment: The plot thickens. Documentation queue seems to have 6 items every time I refresh, however the actual queue appears to be empty.

Comment: I blame caching and call it a day ...

Comment: There is maintenance work going on.  Am I the only one who reads the news?  :)

Comment: If the maintenance work has accidentally, and permanently, cleared the queues then, well, that's just a super bonus this week and @BhargavRao can have a vacation:)

Comment: There is one other [report of a single feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298692/chat-search-not-returning-messages-posted-after-july-8) not working after the move from CO to NY.

Comment: I do repro it now, except for the Close vote and re-open queue

Comment: Yes I am the same except for the close vote and reopen vote queues

Comment: I expect some of the queries to timeout: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261201/stack-overflow-review-page-very-slow-to-load and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298541/tag-pages-and-review-pages-not-loading-properly

Comment: CV, RO and Doc are back.

Comment: FWIW, the review queues on some other sites (Meta SE, EL&U, ELL, Math, Puzzling, Travel, Chemistry, SuperUser, Ask Different, The Workplace) are relatively quiet as well. It looks like new items aren't being added.

Comment: [the state of SO's staff right now](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/017/916/Shits_4b0362_1564208.jpg)

Comment: Can we have "closed all Q in CV queue by accident" That would be a major accomplishment :)

Comment: *Am I the only one who reads the news?* @MartinJames Possibly? There isn't an announcement for this on the blog. I think following them on Twitter is the only way to find out when they're doing maintenance.

Comment: Facing the same problem as of now

Comment: Yes, still happening. I also noted that while the Documentation Changes shows that there are reviews waiting after clicking that option it appears empty

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like our single point of failure scheduler had issues during the [failover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298671/brief-maintenances-planned-for-sat-july-22-2017-at-0001-utc-fri-july-21-8pm) last night. The service crashed when our Colorado SQL servers were under heavy load trying to sync back up with New York. I kicked it and I think thing are working again now:

[image: review queues]

We have plans to replace the scheduler with something much more robust (hopefully soon-ish).

Comment: Oh boy reviewers are in for a long night.

Comment: 499 suggested edits. Such a nice sight. :-|

Comment: @BhargavRao, Actually the nice sight, was 0 suggested edits...

Comment: Dont forget about the 1100+ first posts

Comment: Yes! I'm twice in the screenshot! Where is my price?

Comment: How many single point of failures you guys have? Have you evaluated that? (I know Nick is trying to not become one)