# Triage menu - showing zero

Tags: bug

This morning on my usual task, which is to go over triage question I noticed something strange. All the time Triage count is zero. After couple of refreshes, there was one available. I selected it.

Counter still shows zero, but I can go to next triage by selecting options (skip, looks ok or flagging it).

I made no changes to my system. It was all ok yesterday morning. And I am not under a ban.

System:
Chrome on Mac (Sierra 10.12.2). No Chrome extensions.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail please (aka what browser, any extensions, etc) otherwise it's hard to reproduce the bug.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: No repro here (Firefox on Windows), Triage queue shows about 30 items.

Comment: I'm assuming this is _only_ the Triage queue, the other queues are working normally for you?

Comment: First posts, late answers are all showing zeros, even now as I type.

Comment: But you were able to do a First Post review a minute ago. So it's not a review ban.

Comment: Correct. I am not under a ban.

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] the post to include this information - that you can actually do reviews, and that all counters show 0. Also, if you've tried other browsers, add the result from that as well.

Comment: I could repro this on Chrome 59, Win10, but it appears to have resolved itself over the last few minutes

Comment: @NickA probably another kick https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353675/792066

Comment: @Braiam ah yes that looks like what I experienced